# Вопрос о суффиксоидах

Tags: морфемика

В словах языко-вед, товаро-вед, мыло-вар, пиво-вар и др. "вед", "вар" - суффиксоиды. Так как мы их должны выделять: как корень или как суффикс?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если в морфемном разборе в школе, то однозначно как корень, ведь это КОРНЕВАЯ морфема, если вуз - смотрите в лекции, каждый учёный считает себя правым. Одни обозначают как корень, наверху пишут "суффиксоид", другие как суффикс,третьи  ставят два значка-суффикс и корень.

В любом случае при словообразовательном разборе их отмечают как суффикс, потому что они регулярно используются для образования сложных и сложно-суффиксальных слов. Любая сложная основа состоит из аффиксоидов. А при морфемном разборе возможно и двойное обозначение, но как бы ни обозначили, наверху лучше написать термин СУФФИКСОИД(-вед-, -вар-), ПРЕФИКСОИД (полу-, еже-).

Answer (score 3):

В школьном морфемном разборе мы выделим два корня и соединительную гласную.

**[Как выделять суффиксоиды?](http://human.snauka.ru/2013/07/3605)**

> Аффиксоиды – это корневые морфемы, выступающие в функции аффиксов. Они
>   делятся на префиксоиды (*полу-*) и суффиксоиды (*-вед, -вод* и др.).
>   Суффиксоиды обладают высокой степенью стандартности, подобно
>   суффиксам, например: *стекло-**вар**, языко-**вед**, цвето-**вод**,
>   лесо-**воз**, вино-**дел**, земле-**коп**, теле-**граф**,
>   паро-**образ**-**н**-ый.* Выполняя роль суффиксов, суффиксоиды вместе
>   с тем не перестали осознаваться как корневые морфемы, они находятся на
>   пути перехода из корней в суффиксы, демонстрируя тем самым один из
>   примеров живого развития, изменения языка. По словам Н.М. Шанского,
>   «аффиксоиды, употребляясь как аффиксы, всё же продолжают оставаться и
>   чётко осознаваться корневыми морфемами, или основами, сохраняющими
>   семантические и генетические связи с соответствующими корнями».
>   Поэтому выделять их нужно, видимо, всё же как вторые части сложного
>   слова, то есть членить на корни.

Высшая школа трактует их (аффиксоиды) через функцию в слове, а функция - префикс или суффикс.

> Термином аффиксоид (аффикс + греч. -oid — подобный) обозначаются такие
>   словообразовательные части слов, которые занимают промежуточное
>   положение между корневыми и аффиксальными морфемами (ср. полу-дрёма, полу-ботинки,
>   олен-е-вод, язык-о-вед, нефт-е-воз и т.д.).

**[Суффиксоид (послекорневой аффиксоид) в русском языке](http://www.slovorod.ru/russian-wordform.html)**

> Суффиксоидами являются такие корневые морфемы, которые аналогичны
>   суффиксам (в слове они всегда, естественно, являются опорными основами
>   [ср. китае-вед и синоним кита-ист, собако-вод и собач-ей]).
>
> Суффиксоид - корневая морфема, приобретающая в составе производного
>   слова известные признаки суффиксальной морфемы.
>
> ***К суффиксоидам относятся корневые морфемы, употребляющиеся в функции суффиксов и занимающие в слове их позиции*** (ср. тепл-о-люб,
>   каучук-о-нос...).

P. S.   Нашла и такое определение:

> В современной специальной литературе аффиксоиды обычно определяются
>   как “значимые части слова”, которые “наблюдаются лишь в пределах
>   сложных слов и только в качестве морфем, ***одинаково возможных и в
>   роли служебных, и в роли корневых***”.

И ещё, интересное:

*[ПУШКИНОВЕД](http://slovonline.ru/slovar_sostav/b-16/id-551178/pushkinoved.html)*

> Корень - пушкин  Интерфикс (на графике как суффикс) - о  Суффиксоид
>   (на графике как суффикс) - вед  Флексия (окончание) - нулевая
>
> Это конечно разбор профессиональный, но в качестве корня
>   анализировать 'вед' - ошибка!