# Ещё раз о форманте "полу-"

Tags: морфемика

Формант **"полу-"** в разных известных мне работах называется по-разному: приставкой, префиксом, префиксоидом, начальной частью сложного слова…

В получившем огромное число "лайков" ответе на вопрос [**“Пол”, “полу” - со словами**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/113/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) на нашем форуме он был назван приставкой.

В то же время в комментариях некоторых участников форума в теме [**Лингвистический термин**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450267/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD)
прозвучали и такие мнения:

ПОЛУ - это корень, а не приставка (Sharon);

"полу" сдуру можно назвать приставкой (behemothus).

**А что говорят об этом форманте школьные учебники?**

**Как они рекомендуют его называть?**

Comment: Вы исказили мою мысль. Я не говорил, что **только** сдуру. ))) И вообще вне контекста эта моя фраза выглядит совершенно лишенной смысла. У меня было так, что назвать-то приставкой можно, но основная претензия к обсуждавшейся там формулировке совсем не в этом.

Comment: @behemothus: "Вы исказили мою мысль. Я не говорил, что **только** сдуру. ))) И вообще вне контекста эта моя фраза выглядит совершенно лишенной смысла. У меня было так, что назвать-то приставкой можно..." === **Сдуру?**  Или просто **можно**? :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Про школьные ещё поищем, спешу поделиться находкой:

[Пpeфикcoид – этo **кopнeвaя мopфeмa**, выcтyпaющaя в фyнкции пpиcтaвки (пpeфикca). *Пoлyбoтинки, пoлyoткpытый, пoлyлeжaть.*](http://%D0%9Fpe%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BAco%D0%B8%D0%B4)

Полагаю, что детишкам говорят: [бывает такой корень, а бывает такое числительное](https://mel.fm/pravopisaniye/1082937-half_words), ужатое.

> Если **корень** «пол-» стоит перед согласной (спойлер: кроме буквы «л»),
>   то слово пишется слитно: «проехали полкилометра», «прочитал полкниги»,
>   «встретимся в полдесятого».
>
> Если же **числительное** «пол» отделено от существительного
>   согласованным определением или имеет самостоятельное значение, все
>   слова употребляются отдельно друг от друга: «добавить пол чайной
>   ложки», «прошло пол учебного года». А если убрать определения, то
>   написание тут же меняется: «пол-ложки», «полгода».

Ещё, и тоже не детское:

> При определенных условиях возникают префиксоиды  — морфемы, обладающие
>   значительным сходством с собственно префиксами, однако не утратившие
>   генетической связи с корнями. 1968 // «Русский язык в школе» ◆
>   Префиксоид характеризуется способностью выступать в качестве
>   самостоятельного слова и в то же время в качестве префикса. Б. Н.
>   Головин, Е. Ф. Киров, Л. И. Ручина, «Теория языкознания и русистика:
>   наследие Б.Н. Головина : сборник статей по материалам международной
>   научной конференции, посвященной 85-летию профессора Бориса
>   Николаевича Головина», 2001 г.

А [Справка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4) на что нам дадена?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако достучаться до вопроса № 179373 не представляется возможным (я уж и циферки меняла...).

Зато ой что нашла! И где?! А здесь, педагог отвечает:

[При морфемном разборе возможно и двойное обозначение, но как бы ни обозначили, наверху лучше написать термин СУФФИКСОИД (-вед-, -вар-), ПРЕФИКСОИД (полу-, еже-).](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428460/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%85)

И на закуску: Справка тоже говорит о ***пол-*** как о числительном и корне.

[Вопрос № 299463](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=299463)

> В справочной литературе указывается, что слова, начинающиеся с "пол-",
>   не имеют рода. Как же тогда правильно построить предложение типа
>   "Полкласса получил (-а, -о, -и) пятерки"? Для некоторых таких слов
>   словари все же определяют род. Например, указывается, что "пол-литра"
>   женского рода. И что же такое "пол-", корень или приставка?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> При подлежащем, выраженном сложным существительным, первую часть
>   которого образует **числительное пол-** (полчаса, полгода и т. п.),
>   сказуемое обычно ставится в форме единственного числа, а в прошедшем
>   времени – в среднем роде, например: *полчаса пройдет незаметно,
>   полгорода участвовало в демонстрации; Полголовы уже осталось* (Чехов).
>   Но если при этих словах имеется определение в форме именительного
>   падежа множественного числа, то и сказуемое ставится во множественном
>   числе, например: *Первые полчаса прошли незаметно; Остальные полдома
>   уцелели от пожара.*
>
> Таким образом, верно: *Полкласса получило пятерки.* В составе слова
>   *пол-* – это **корень**.
>
> ---

[Ещё о **числительном** *пол-*.](http://www.fio.ru/pravila/orfografiya/chislitelnoe-pol/)

Comment: Спасибо за участие в обсуждении! Отвечу чуть позже.

Answer (score 2):

**ПОЛУ – это префиксоид.**

ПРЕФИКСОИД

**Корневая морфема, выступающая в функции приставки** (префикса). Полуботинки, полуоткрытый, полулежать. Ежедневный, ежевечерний, ежемесячный.

Словарь лингвистических терминов. 2012

**А что это значит?**

Вероятно, корневая морфема имеет определенное  самостоятельное значение, в отличие от приставки.

**Пре́фикс:** префикс (приставка) — в языкознании: морфема, стоящая перед корнем и **изменяющая его лексическое или грамматическое значение.**

Из словаря Кузнецова:

ПОЛУ... Первая часть **сложных слов**. 1. Вносит зн.: **половина** чего-л.

Но в сложном слове ***полу***- не может быть приставкой, то есть **формант должен считаться корнем**.

**Вывод:**

***Полу-*** определяется как корень (сравнить: *половина*), а значение приставки — это его дополнительная функция. Она связана с тем, что корень слова *половина* усекается  до форманта пол-/полу-  и начинает функционировать самостоятельно как приставка.

В школе вряд ли будут использовать термин ***префиксоид***, поэтому там придется сделать этот выбор: корень или приставка? **При морфемном разборе**  формант называется корнем.

Пример разбора слова полумрак: ***пол* — корень.**

[https://kartaslov.ru/разбор-слова-по-составу/полумрак](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA)

Comment: Почему вы считаете пол(у)- корнем, если этот элемент не ведет себя как корень? Где слыхано, что корень регулярно (!) присоединяется без соед. гласных к другому корню и при этом лишь модифицирует (!), а не радикально меняет лексическое значение?

Comment: Вы меня не совсем поняли, вероятно.  ПОЛУ -  это префиксоид, у него двойная природа.  Он отличается и от корня, и от приставки, .и я подробно объяснила чем. Но при разборе предложения. который обычно делается в школе, формант считается корнем. И в словаре написано, что слова с ПОЛУ считаются сложными. Где же это слыхано (я использую здесь ваше выражение), чтобы приставка входила в сложное слово вместо корня.

Comment: Спасибо за участие в обсуждении! Отвечу чуть позже.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Кстати, я еще учебники посмотрела. В новом справочнике для начальной школе никакого названия нет  (написание пол-/полу-). В учебнике для 10 -11 кл. (2007) пол- назван начальным элементом.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуюсь возможностью прокомментировать ответы Галины и Шарон здесь, в окне ответа на собственный вопрос (в окнах, предназначенных для комментариев, места, к сожалению, мало)...

**Galina Avanesova** писала:

> Если же **числительное** «пол» отделено от существительного
>   согласованным определением...
>
> При подлежащем, выраженном сложным существительным, первую часть
>   которого образует **числительное** *пол-*...

Да, Галина. **ПОЛ** многими лингвистами действительно считается числительным. Но не **ПОЛУ**…

**ПОЛ** существует в языке как самостоятельная лексема, **ПОЛУ** же — только в связанном виде. И потому отнести **ПОЛУ** к какой-либо части речи не представляется возможным.

Мельчук И.А. в работе ***Русский язык в модели "Смысл — текст"***, обосновывая принадлежность **ПОЛ** к числительным, так, к примеру, отзывается о **ПОЛУ** (со значением 'примерно = половина'):

> Я,  сознательно не поднимаю вопроса о том, является ли формант
>   **ПОЛУ-**  префиксом или начальной частью сложного слова, т.е. следует ли здесь говорить о производных или сложных словах. Для моих целей
>   ответ на этот вопрос не существенен.

*"Префиксом или начальной частью сложного слова..."*

**Sharon** писала:

> Из словаря Кузнецова:
>
> **ПОЛУ...** Первая часть сложных слов. 1. Вносит зн.: половина чего-л.
>
> Но в сложном слове ***полу-*** не может быть приставкой, то есть
>   формант должен считаться корнем.

**Наверное, так…** Но все ли лингвисты считают слова с **ПОЛУ** сложными? Судя по приведённой мной выше цитате из Мельчука — похоже, не все.

Ну и, во-вторых, словарь Кузнецова — это же ведь не школьный учебник.

**А что в учебниках?**

Встретил в одном из школьных справочников [**Радион А.А. "Краткий справочник по орфографии и пунктуации"**], упоминание о том, что в школьной программе префиксоид **ПОЛУ** относят к корням:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Корнем **ПОЛУ** назван и в [**Баранов М.Т. "Школьный орфографический словарь"**].

В то же время в пособии [[**Горбунова И. Н. "Занимательная лингвистика. 4 класс: программа, материалы к занятиям"**]](https://books.google.ru/books?id=JsmEDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA76&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqmd7ZpMvhAhWK0KYKHRJWD1IQ6AEINjAC#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%22&f=false) речь идёт уже о приставке:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приставкой называет **ПОЛУ** и Марина Баронова в пособии [**"Русский язык. Экспресс-репетитор для подготовки к ЕГЭ"**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ARrMAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%A3-%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&source=bl&ots=u0ah8IFOhn&sig=ACfU3U2Pj8RN6y1smwYLPhw-xxQnmXocog&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPvIqNu83hAhW8wsQBHR9eBTAQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%A3-%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&f=true):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ну и какой же ответ тогда будет считаться правильным при сдаче ЕГЭ?**

**Приставка? Корень?**

Comment: При сдаче ЕГЭ лучше называть ПОЛУ другими словами: формант, элемент, начальный элемент. Можно и префиксоид упомянуть, если разбираешься в теме.  Раньше формант называли преимущественно корнем, но только не приставкой. Сейчас  отдельные лингвисты рискуют назвать его приставкой, но, разумеется, не в школьных учебниках. Тенденция изменилась, поэтому лучше ей соответствовать, выражаясь нейтрально. Иначе в любой момент могут, к примеру,  задать такие вопросы : Как вы понимаете  функционирование форманта   в качестве приставки? Почему мы не можем отнести его  только к приставкам?